# Random clickable div move around a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this javascript code that make the div randomly move around web page,but i am not understanding how to make it that it does not flow continuously,its like if user click then it move and then stops there and whenever it clicks again it moves to another random position and after 5 time it shows a message and disappears.I am not getting how to make this animation not like a flow but like a leaf falling from a tree.

here is the jsfiddle : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/15/)

below is the javascript code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
animateDiv();

});

function makeNewPosition(){

   // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
   var h = $(window).height() - 50;
   var w = $(window).width() - 50;

   var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
   var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

   return [nh,nw];    

   }

  function animateDiv(){
  var newq = makeNewPosition();
  var oldq = $('.a').offset();
  var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

   $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
    animateDiv();        
    });

   };

  function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

   var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
   var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

   var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

   var speedModifier = 0.1;

   var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

   return speed;

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `CSS3 transitions`, they hare hardware accelerated that mean smoother animations:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 0;
    
    $('.a').click( function () {
        if ( ++counter < 5 ) {
            var pos =  makeNewPosition();
            this.style.left = pos[1] +'px';
            this.style.top  = pos[0] +'px';
        }
        else if ( counter = 5 ) {
            this.style.display = 'none';
            alert( 'Your message' );
        }
    });
});

function makeNewPosition(){
    
    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;
    
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    
    return [nh,nw];    
    
}
```

```css
div.a {
  width : 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;

  position: fixed;      
  left    : 0px;
  top     : 0px;
  -webkit-transition: left 2s, top 2s;
     -moz-transition: left 2s, top 2s;
       -o-transition: left 2s, top 2s;
          transition: left 2s, top 2s;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'></div>
```

Comment: Even better: use CSS translate to move the element http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/z2s1qpzr/. Top and left positioning do not offer the possibility of subpixel rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The animateDiv function calls itself at the end, so as soon as it reaches its destination it picks a new destination and goes there. Here it is with the recursive callback removed:

```
function animateDiv(){
  var newq = makeNewPosition();
  var oldq = $('.a').offset();
  var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

  $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed);
};
```

And an updated fiddle, which now requires clicking the box to animate it: http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/3975/

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/3976/) ?

```js
var isStart = true;
$(".a").click(function () {
    animateDiv(isStart);
});

function makeNewPosition() {

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];

}

function animateDiv() {
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.a').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
    if (isStart) {

        $('.a').animate({
            top: newq[0],
            left: newq[1]
        }, speed, function () {
            animateDiv();
        });
        isStart = false;
    } else {
        $('.a').stop();
        isStart = true;
    }


};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

```css
div.a {
width: 50px;
height:50px;
 background-color:red;
position:fixed;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'></div>
```